# VBS to list file names NOT matching given extension

Tags: vbscript

I have been working on the following VBS.  This will search a parent folder and all child / subfolders and print any file with the provided extension (doc, docx, msg, ppt, txt) and came up with the following.  I am new to VBS but I would like to define the file extensions to IGNORE, listing all others.  I have the directory listing of each file type working but I don't want to have to set a NEXT for each file type.  I was able to use the <> code in the top section to show all files that don't match an extension using:

```
If objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFileName) <> "jpg" then
```

But this doesn't work in the lower part:

```
if LCase(InStr(1,Files, "jpg")) > 1 then Wscript.Echo Files
```

I would also like to be able to define multiple file types; like

```
    If objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFileName) <> "jpg" OR "jpeg" OR "tiff"
```

Lastly I need to output to a text file, not a windows script msg box.

Can anyone help?  Sorry for typos or confusion, English is not my first language.

```
Dim fso

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set FSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
Set f = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\temp\output.txt", 2)

objStartFolder = "C:\Test"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile in colFiles 
strFileName = objFile.Name
If objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFileName) = "x937" then
Wscript.Echo objFile.Name 
End If

Next

For Each objFile in colFiles 
strFileName = objFile.Name
If objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFileName) = "docx" then
    Wscript.Echo objFile.Name 
End If

Next

For Each objFile in colFiles 
strFileName = objFile.Name
If objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFileName) = "doc" then
    Wscript.Echo objFile.Name 
End If

Next

For Each objFile in colFiles 
strFileName = objFile.Name
If objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFileName) = "txt" then
    Wscript.Echo objFile.Name 
End If

Next

For Each objFile in colFiles 
strFileName = objFile.Name
If objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFileName) = "msg" then
    Wscript.Echo objFile.Name 
End If

Next

ShowSubfolders objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)

For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders 
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path) 
    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files 
    for each Files in colFiles 
if LCase(InStr(1,Files, "msg")) > 1 then Wscript.Echo Files 
    next
    ShowSubFolders Subfolder 
Next 

For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders 
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path) 
    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files 
    for each Files in colFiles 
if LCase(InStr(1,Files, "txt")) > 1 then Wscript.Echo Files 
    next
    ShowSubFolders Subfolder 

Next 

For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders 
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path) 
    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files 
    for each Files in colFiles 
if LCase(InStr(1,Files, "ppt")) > 1 then Wscript.Echo Files 
    next
    ShowSubFolders Subfolder 
Next 

For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders 
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path) 
    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files 
    for each Files in colFiles 
if LCase(InStr(1,Files, "xls")) > 1 then Wscript.Echo Files 
    next
    ShowSubFolders Subfolder 
Next 

For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders 
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path) 
    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files 
    for each Files in colFiles 
if LCase(InStr(1,Files, "doc")) > 1 then Wscript.Echo Files 
    next
    ShowSubFolders Subfolder 

Next 

End Sub
```

Comment: *But this doesn't work in the lower part: `if LCase(InStr(1,Files, "jpg")) > 1 then Wscript.Echo Files`* I believe the reason for this is because `Files` is an entire object and you only one the `.Name` property of it, so you should replace it with `Files.Name`

Answer (score 0):

You can check all of the extensions in one loop:

```
For Each objFile in colFiles 
    Dim strFileName : strFileName = objFile.Name
    Dim strExtension : strExtension = LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFileName))

    If strExtension <> "txt" And _
        strExtension <> "jpg" And _
        strExtension <> "msg" And _
        strExtension <> "docx" Then

        Wscript.Echo objFile.Name 
    End If
Next
```

I just put a bunch of random extensions in because it wasn't clear which ones you want to ignore.  Make sure you put them all in lowercase so the comparison works because the code converts the actual extension to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

For exporting the output to a txt file, the below code might work

Function TextFile_Generate()

```
strFile = "C:\...\ReportName.txt"
strValue = "output text..."

Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.FileExists(strFile) Then
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile,8, True)
Else
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFile,True)
End If
objFile.Write strValue & vbCrLf
objFile.Close

Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO =Nothing
```

End Function